# Google App Engine proxy

Tags: python, google-app-engine, proxy

What would be the simplest implementation of a proxy written for GAE, which relays every URL (including POST, and header data) to a remote HTTP host, and return with it's result (with special consideration to error codes)?
Please apply KISS principles!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found [this proxy app](http://code.google.com/p/downy/source/browse/#hg/proxy) from the [Downy](http://code.google.com/p/downy/) project works very well.

Answer (score 1):

How about [this one][1] ?

[1]: https://web.archive.org/web/20130102032034/http://google.com:80/codesearch/p#SKzQ5XqR4js/trunk/README&q=appengine http proxy

Answer (score 1):

Downy, did not work with ajax/GAS.
Use http://code.google.com/p/bs2grproxy/ BS2 GAE Reverse Proxy. I used it, with ajax (GAS), works fine.

Comment: Yes, bs2grproxy is better, and downy proxy only copy over Content-Type header